# fatal error after typo3 upgrade

Tags: typo3-6.2.x, typo3-4.5

After I upgraded a typo3 4.5 LTS to Typo3 6.2 LTS I get a fatal error saying:

> Fatal error: Class '\' not found in /home/www/dev2.mysite.com/typo3_src-6.2.13/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Cache/CacheFactory.php on line 75

Do you have any idea how I can fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

**clean your cache** -- hard way:
goto the `install tool` -> `important actions` -> `clean cache`

remove everything in `typo3temp/`  (use `rm -rf typo3temp/*` )

Then try again.

Comment: I did it many times but not working ... moreover when I click on clean cache the same problem appears. I mostly can't do anything with my site now

Comment: did you also remove all in typo3temp manually ?  
Also try to truncate all cf_* tables in your db (backup first of course )  Also be sure you have done the complete upgrade cycle (in install tool)